# How to filter an array by keys using another array

Tags: php, arrays

I working now for a couple of hours on my project, i have some key's from a early array that i want to loop to my new array and pick the value of the key's that i have from the early array.

Early array:

```
$old_keys = ['key1','key2','key3'];
```

New array:

```
$result = ['key1' => 'foo', 'key2' => 'bar', 'key6' => 'ipsum'];
```

Output that i want is:

```
$output = ['foo', 'bar'];
```

This is what i made:

```
foreach ($old_keys as $old_key) {

    $output[] = array_column($result, $old_key);

}
return $output;
```

What did i wrong because everything what i get is a empty array

Thanks a lot!

Update:

```
$keys = array_flip($old_keys);

$output = array_values(array_intersect_key($result, $keys));

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($output);
```

The $output is now filled with the multidimensional array of $result, but the values 'foo' and 'bar' are in the second level of this multidimensional array. The problem is, i get only the first level of this array and not the second level.

example of the output:

```
[
 [0] => string
 [1] => string
 [
  [key1] => foo
  [key2] => bar
 ]
]
```

What i want is:

```
[
 [0] => string
 [1] => string
 [3] => foo
 [4] => bar
]
```

Solution:

```
$flat = iterator_to_array(new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($result)), true);
```

Comment: While you are still here, you may want to re-title your question, because it is not an accurate way to describe your process.

Comment: Do you have a better title ?

Comment: perhaps something like: _How to filter an array by keys using another array_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter the `$result` array using `$old_keys`, but use the `$old_keys` values as keys:

```
$old_keys = array_flip(['key1','key2','key3']);
$result = ['key1' => 'foo', 'key2' => 'bar', 'key6' => 'ipsum'];
$output=array_intersect_key($result,$old_keys);
print_r($output);
```

If you want to re-index the keys in the result, replace the `$output` declaration with:

```
$output=array_values(array_intersect_key($result,$old_keys));
```

Comment: Thanks, but i get so as i expect an empty array as output, because result is a multidimensional array.

Comment: @PieterDijkstra In your question, `$result` is not a multidimensional array.  Please update your question to present `$result` as a multidimensional array.  You must offer me a correct sample to manipulate so I can replicate the issue and solve the problem.

Comment: I don't know if I need to explain this bit, but my code replaces yours.  You don't need to do any looping.  And you can just `return` the `print_r` value.  If there are no old keys in the result array, output will be an empty array.

Comment: see my update, i've already update my code with yours but it doesn't work on the way i want.

Comment: Something else must be wrong with your code, because this works: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/77d3e0738008dacffdef8f0dfa28c74073b93a8e

Comment: This is what happend in my code,http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f716481e15d26108412160f6dd9da677ada6c40c

Comment: Why have you muddled up a perfectly good 2d array by adding the new subarray?  Please join those two array together to maintain the 2d array, or else you are making everything harder on yourself.  Where ever you are concatenating the new sub array, just use this:  `$result['key2'] = 'bar';`

Comment: Or declare the subarray as `$new` and merge `$result` with `$new` before filtering with `array_intersect_key()`